# How can I retrieve all users that have been assigned to a Service Principal in one call with navigation properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

How can I retrieve all users within a Service Principal with navigation properties such as Manager and properties such as Full name using Microsoft Graph API in as few as possible calls?

I'm using the Microsoft.Graph package and I've tried:

**Attempt 1:**

```
await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["objectId"].AppRoleAssignedTo.Request().GetAsync();
```

But this gives me only the Ids, which is 'okay' but then I would have to get all users separately, which would make for a lot of calls to the Graph API.

I could use the DirectoryObjects to get all users at once but that does not allow me to expand on the Manager property.

For example:

```
var users = await graphClient.DirectoryObjects.GetByIds(principals.Select(p => p.PrincipalId.ToString()), new string[1] { "User" }).Request().Expand("manager").PostAsync();
```

Gives me a error:

```
Could not find a property named 'manager' on type 'microsoft.graph.directoryObject'.
```

**Attempt 2:**

I've also tried to get the users by using a filter

```
await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("appRoleAssignments/any(u:u/principalId eq objectId)").Expand(u => u.Manager).GetAsync();
```

But that gives me a error:

```
Request_UnsupportedQuery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code like this:

```
var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("id in ('{objectId1}', '{objectId2}', ..., '{objectIdn}')").Expand(u => u.Manager).Select("displayName").GetAsync();
```

Ideally, this will use just one call to return the data you need.

**BUT** based on the requirement "in as few as possible calls", we will have to face a problem, that is, we need to put all the object ids into the request, which may cause the request to be too long and eventually fail.

I didn't test this scene and it's just a direction which may be helpful.

I still recommend that you use loop to get the information.